# Choosing images from many images in one PNG file

Tags: image, web, png

My question is while developing any web site i use many images stop, next, back, prev for doing some stuff, i put them in different folder and access them separately. But when i see other web site and try to get the images like reply, post , Search so that i can use them for my site or use the color combination the way they have use. What i see is, i get many images in one png image. I want to ask is what is purpose of putting all images in one PNG image and while accessing one image from there how they access that particular image from those images. If any one can provide some code then it will be very great and also the advantages and disadvantages.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is sprites. Sprite is a collection of small icons in one .png image. The benefit for this is increasing the speed of website loading, these small icons are grouped together which results in one small png image as compared to each one these imgs stored individually.

The images in the sprites are then accessed by the background position.

The best e.g.
http://www.spritecow.com

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply...and i understood what it is but...how can i use the Sprite thing in my web site...plz help me out regarding this....do i have to use code or is there anything readymade like this....

Comment: You have to create the sprite in Photoshop. It can be of any width and height and the background has to be transparent, no background at all. After that, drag icons/images on this PSD and position them in a proper way, give some proper space between these images. Once done, save it as png.

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/
Scroll down to the end and you can see egs of sprites.

Load the sprite in the spritecow.com and you will be able to get the bg position of each of them, copy and paste the code in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Read about **CSS sprites**. For example:

http://alistapart.com/article/sprites

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

http://spritegen.website-performance.org/